# export * not working

Tags: javascript, import, ecmascript-6

I have following folder structure. I am trying to export component in bulk but it does not work for me but I did not find any error on this.

**/General**

**index.js**

```
export * from './Card'
```

**/General/Card**

**index.js**

```
export Gold from './Gold';
export Silver from './Silver';
```

It works if directly import component in general's index.js like

```
export Gold from './Card/Gold';
export Silver from './Card/Silver';
```

Comment: `export`? Do you mean `import`?

Comment: @evolutionxbox: yes it is export thanks for correcting me. Edited my answer

Comment: You are trying to import * a directory path?

Comment: Ok. That's not the syntax for exports "components". See https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/web/javascript/reference/statements/export

Comment: @evolutionxbox i can see _`export * from …;`_

Comment: @jai I can too... _"Exporting defaults: The following syntax does not export a default export from the imported module `export * from …;`"_ -- or am I completely misunderstanding something?

Comment: @evolutionxbox ohh i get it now.

Comment: @evolutionxbox: I have seen this working on one of app where we were using export default className and the export * statement was just working fine. Maybe it depends on some babel version?

Comment: export const Silver .  event not worked for me

Comment: `export Gold from './Gold';` is not valid. You want `export {default as Gold} from './Gold';`